# Simultaneous subsitution in Perl

Tags: string, perl, global, substitution

Below is a script where I am trying to reverse and then substitute (A=>T, T=>A, G=>C, C=>G).

VERSION 1

```
#!/usr/bin/perl    
my $str="AAAAAGCTTGC";
$str_rev=scalar reverse ("$str"),"\n";
print"My original string: $str\n";
print "My reversed string: $str_rev\n";

$str_rev =~ s/A/T/g;
$str_rev =~ s/T/A/;
$str_rev =~ s/G/C/g;
$str_rev =~ s/C/G/;
print"My substituted reversed string: $str_rev\n";
```

OUTPUT:

```
My original string: AAAAAGCTTGC
My reversed string: CGTTCGAAAAA
My substituted reversed string: GCATCCTTTTT
```

Global for all substitutions (Version 2)

```
$str_rev =~ s/A/T/g;
$str_rev =~ s/T/A/g;
$str_rev =~ s/G/C/g;
$str_rev =~ s/C/G/g;
print"My substituted reversed string: $str_rev\n";
```

OUTPUT:

```
My original string: AAAAAGCTTGC
My reversed string: CGTTCGAAAAA
My substituted reversed string: GGAAGGAAAAA
```

In first version, I observe that the substitution which are not global, are being substituted once (obviously, since its not global). And in version 2, since it process the code from top down, the last substitution skips out the remaining "G". I wanted all of the substitutions in parallel. How can I achieve that in a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had `use strict` and `use warnings` in place you would have seen the warning

```
Useless use of a constant ("\n") in void context
```

referring to this line

```
$str_rev=scalar reverse ("$str"),"\n";
```

I don't understand what you're trying to do here apart from reversing the string. What is the stray newline string for? Also, `scalar` is superfluous and putting the variable in double quotes is wrong (although none of these errors affect your program in this case). This should be written

```
my $str_rev = reverse $str;
```

Here is a solution showing the correct code and using `s///` instead of `tr///`. Apart from the fixes this is for your interest, as it is best to use transliterate.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.014;

my $str = "AAAAAGCTTGC";

print "My original string: $str\n";

my %map =  ( A => 'T', T => 'A', G => 'C', C => 'G' );
my $str_rev = reverse $str =~ s/([ATGC])/$map{$1}/gr;

print "My substituted reversed string: $str_rev\n";
```

**output**

```
My original string: AAAAAGCTTGC
My substituted reversed string: GCAAGCTTTTT
```

Answer (score 8):

Use y (transliterate) instead:

```
 $str_rev =~ tr/ATGC/TAGC/;
```